# Live Messenger does not run after setting services to manual?

Tags: windows, windows-live-messenger

I recently tried to fix an issue by changing as many windows services as possible from automatic to manual.

Since then, I cannot login to Windows Live Messenger.

Some obvious services which weren't running were DNS and DHCP.  However, since starting them, the problem remains: Live Messenger simply won't sign in.

What are some essential services for Live Messenger?

Thanks.

Comment: I would revise what you did. Many services are set to automatic for a reason. Setting them to manual doesn't fix the original issue, it will only create new issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DCOM Server Process Launcher was the service I needed to start.

Answer (score 1):

The **Windows Live ID Sign-in Assistant** service is probably the culprit of your login problems.

Comment: This service is not part of my WinXP installation.  It was the DCOM Server Process Launcher which needed to started.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention Windows XP... And I also guess you must have an old version of Windows Live then, as this is a standard service as far as I know of it. The DCOM Server Process Launcher is indeed a very important service, by enabling it you will solve more problems than just this one. Windows XP allows you to disable such important services while Windows Vista and Windows 7 won't allow you unless you do registry hacks for them. But well, there could be more services that cause this problem so there isn't really a single answer...